# how to open version history using SPSecurityTrimmedControl

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, object-model

I am using SPSecurityTrimmedControl to view version history of list for users who have more than read permissions like this

<.SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl ID="SPSecurityTrimmedControl1" PermissionsString= "EditListItems" runat= "server">

<.a href="??">version history   //line 3

<./SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>

At line 3, in href, what should i put here (??), When i click on version history, I want to open small window showing Version History here. How i do this??

Answer (score 2):

Paste into the following code your list id and item id:

```
<a href="#" onclick="SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog( {url: '/_layouts/Versions.aspx?list={list guid}&ID={item id}&IsDlg=1'} ); return false;">version history</a>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I am pretty new to SharePoint. i want to display version history dialog for the current item from my web page. I could not put static item Id here in the above link. I want some piece of code where i can put dynamic item Id. (The current item id which user has selected.). I guess i need to write some code using server side api for this. Can you please help me by sending that piece of code or any useful link. Thanks..

Comment: Correct code to get selected list item is below

Answer (score 0):

You can use get the current selected item in the LVWP by using Client side object model code. An example would be like this:

```
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
    var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
    var itemIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
    itemIds += selectedItems[i].id + ",";
    }
```